# calculate the difference in days from two dates in C

Tags: c, timestamp, typedef, date-difference, time.h

I have a problem with my code: I need to calculate a difference time between two date. I have the dates inside a struct.

Why the result is 0? I'm blocked here for 2 days.

```
typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} DIAGNOSISDATE;

DIAGNOSISDATE dateDiagnosis[3];

typedef struct {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} HEALINGDATE;

HEALINGDATE dateHealing[3];

typedef struct {
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char fiscalCode[17];
    STATESICK stateSick;
    DIAGNOSISDATE dateDiagnosis;
    HEALINGDATE dateHealing;
} SICKREGION;

SICKREGION sickregion[SIZESICK];
```

and I have my function here:

```
void timeDiff() {
    struct tm ts;
    char buf[80];
    //int getTimeDiff = 0;
    long total = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                struct tm time1;
                time1.tm_mday = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateHealing.day;
                time1.tm_mon = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateHealing.month;
                time1.tm_year = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateHealing.year;
                struct tm time0;
                time0.tm_mday = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateDiagnosis.day;
                time0.tm_mon = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateDiagnosis.month;
                time0.tm_year = region[i].hospital[j].sickregion[k].dateDiagnosis.year;
                time_t rawtime = difftime(mktime(&time1), mktime(&time0));
                // Total = (Total + rawtime);

                ts = *localtime(&rawtime);
                //Total = (rawtime + Total) + 1;
                total += (rawtime / 86400);
            }
        }
    }
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%j", &ts);
    // printf("%s\n", buf);
    printf("%ld\n", total);
}
```

I don't understand where is the problem. 
Anyway in my macbook it will run, in windows not work. :/
the code is the same.
I tried to dichiarate `the struct tm` 0 `and struct tm 1` inside my typedef but nothing differences. anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: If your problem is the difference between 2 dates, can you remove the `HOSPITAL` and other unrelated stuff from the question and show the `difftime` function instead?

Comment: Why make `DIAGNOSISDATE` and `HEALINGDATE` 2 distinct types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior because you do not initialize the other members of `tm_time1` and `tm_time2`. A quick fix for this is:

```
    struct tm time1 = { 0 };
    struct tm time2 = { 0 };
```

Another problem is you store the return value of `difftime` of type `double` into a `time_t` variable. The time difference may be negative and `time_t` might be an unsigned type, causing `rawtime / 86400` to produce a large positive number. You should probably use a `long` to store the time difference and reject the data if this difference comes out negative.

With this problem fixed, `long rawtime = difftime(mktime(&time1), mktime(&time0));` will compute the time difference between the 2 dates at 0:00:00 am in seconds.

Dividing this by `86400` is not completely correct as the difference may not be an exact multiple of 86400 if there were one or more local time changes due to DST in the interval. I suggest you use:

```
    total += (rawtime + 3600 * 3) / 86400; // difference in days, ignoring DST.
```

Alternately, you could define `rawtime` as a `double` and use:

```
    total += round(rawtime / 86400.0);
```

Finally, computing `ts = *localtime(&rawtime);` makes no sense at all: converting a number of seconds to a date is only meaningful if this number of seconds represents a valid date. `rawtime` is a duration, not a valid date.